# Node split string by last space

Tags: node.js

```
var str="72 tocirah abba tesh sneab";
```

I currently have this string and want a new string that is called "72 tocirah abba tesh". What is the best way to do this in node/Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Another one-liner:

```
"72 tocirah abba tesh sneab".split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ")
```

Basically, you split the string using the space separator, slice the resulting array removing the last item, and join the array using the space separator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`, like:

```
"72 tocirah abba tesh sneab".replace(/\s\w+$/, '')
```

(This replaces the last space and word with an empty string)

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it like that:

```
let str = "72 tocirah abba tesh sneab"
```

Split by " ":

```
let list = str.split(" ") // [72,tocirah,abba,tesh,sneab]
```

Remove the last element using pop():

```
list.pop() // [72,tocirah,abba,tesh]
```

Then join it back together:

```
str = list.join(" ") // 72 tocirah abba tesh
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is one of the ways to handle this.

#### use lastIndexOf function

```js
const lastSpacePosition = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
// in case there is no space in the statement. take the whole string as result.

if(lastSpacePosition < 0) {
    lastSpacePosition = str.length;
}

str.substr(0, lastSpacePosition);
```

There are other ways to handle this using `regEx`, `split->join` as well